# What are the public IP address of client PCs which access Internet via proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy

If I have three PCs in local network to access Internet via a proxy server which has a static public IPv4  218.106.125.138

If the three PCs access https://www.whatismyip.com/ to show their public IPv4, will these three PCs show the same public IP address  218.106.125.138 ?

Client PC1:  10.201.168.100

Client PC2:  10.201.168.101

Client PC3:  10.201.168.102

Server  1:   10.201.168.200   and  static public IPv4 is 218.106.125.138

Comment: Probably. Why don't you try it & see?

Comment: I havn't three PCs and server, so I can't test it